# split time data in Javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, loops, time, split

I'm trying to create a dynamic calendar.
I have opening and closing hours.

I would like to make a loop to get all the half hour slots between these two times.

The goal is to create a div that contains the list of these schedules.

do you have a method, an idea please to help me achieve this?

My data, inside a json document, looks like this:

```
"minMax": {
                "min": "07:00",
                "max": "18:00"
            }
```

(I have already retrieved the day) my goal is to display the schedules.

```
const minHour = week[weekNumber].minMax.min // => 07:00
const maxHour = week[weekNumber].minMax.max // => 18:00
```

The problem is that I don't know how to split the schedules by half hour between the min hour and the max hour.

Comment: by half an hour you mean 30 minutes intervals?

Comment: Yes every 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var convertValue  = time => ((hour,min) => hour*2 + min/30)(...time.split(':').map(parseFloat)),
    toTime = int => [Math.floor(int/2), int%2 ? '30' : '00'].join(':'),
    range  = (from, to) => Array(to-from+1).fill().map((_,i) => from + i),
    halfHourInterval = (t1, t2) => range(...[t1, t2].map(convertValue)).map(toTime);

console.log(halfHourInterval('07:00', '15:30'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information you gave I came up with this solution to generate half hour slots. If there is any corrections needed to be made or edge cases to handle, please let me know.

```
function halfHourSlots(min, max) {
  let slots = [];

  let [minHour] = min.split(':');
  let [maxHour] = max.split(':');

  minHour = Number(minHour);
  maxHour = Number(maxHour);

  while (minHour != maxHour) {
    let halfHourString = `${minHour}:30`.padStart(
      2,
      '0'
    );
    minHour += 1;

    let hourString = `${
      minHour == 24 ? '00' : minHour
    }:00`.padStart(2, '0');

    slots.push(halfHourString);
    slots.push(hourString);
  }

  return slots;
}

console.log(halfHourSlots('07:00', '18:00'));
```